# Installing IOS sdk in xcode on lion

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk, osx-lion

I have installed lion and afterwards I installed Xcode. But I have no IOS SDK.
If I look inside the directory: `/Developer/SDKs/`  I see a sdk for mac os x 10.6 and for 
10.7 but no IOS SDK.

When I run my projects or I create a new blank project that uses this sdk I get the following build error:

```
ibtoold(5057,0x7fff73646960) malloc
auto_zone_set_associative_ref: object should point to a GC block or a global address, otherwise associations will leak. Break on auto_zone_association_error() to debug.
```

Any Ideas? I've tried re-installing it twice.

I am starting to think there is some bug using lion and Xcode together, I am going to ask this question on the apple developer forum. If I get an answer there, ill post it here.

Comment: Questions regarding tools that programmers use _are_ on topic according to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Would Super User _really_ be a place for the OP to get help on this? I tend to think not.

Comment: anyone found a solution yet? Been having same problem since january!

Comment: @DaMainBoss, [download Xcode 4.1 for Lion](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action#downloads). As described on that page, it *"is the complete Xcode developer toolset for Mac, iPhone, and iPad. It includes the Xcode IDE, iOS Simulator, and all required tools and frameworks for building Mac OS X and iOS apps."*

Comment: Yeah i have dat but it always crashes when i open my xib file! Have a look at this --> http://pastebin.com/BxMKqN6r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try doing a full clean un-install.

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

Then make sure you download the LION version of XCode 4, I believe it's a free version now.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

The iOS SDK includes Xcode, but Xcode doesn't necessarily includethe iOS SDK. You should download and install the iOS SDK if that's what you want.

Comment: Ty for your reply, I googled it but you can't download the IOS SDK without Xcode 4, They are distributed together.

Comment: anyone found a solution yet? Been having same problem since january!